# Parsing attributes from sql query in Ruby on Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

In my Ruby on Rails app I have the following query:

```
  SELECT
    u.id,
    ROUND(COALESCE(AVG(CAST(r.score AS FLOAT)),0)::numeric, 1) AS user_average_rating

    FROM users u
      LEFT JOIN video_chats v ON v.user_id = u.id
      LEFT JOIN ratings r     ON r.video_chat_id = v.id

    GROUP BY u.id;
```

Which returns:

```
 id | user_average_rating 
----+---------------------
  7 |                 2.0
  3 |                 0.0
  5 |                 0.0
  1 |                 0.0
  4 |                 0.0
(5 rows)
```

This sql query is a database which is used in my models. The problem that when I use `user_average_rating` in Ruby on Rails it returns `0.2e1` instead of `2.0`. I can call `to_f` method on `0.2e1` and then it returns me correct result but I want to get correct result from PostgreSQL without calling any additional methods. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: This is a `BigDecimal` object and is very similar to a `Float` object except that it does not have the famous floating point issue

Comment: So how can I fix my problem?

Comment: There is no problem there. It is just displayed differently than a Float. It will act like one. The only place where it will be displayed in that `#<BigDecimal:9537330,'0.3E-6',9(36)>` format, it will be in the Rails console. If you print it out on a HTML page, text of anything, it will be printed out as a regular Float (easily) readable by humans

Comment: Let me know if you don't think this is a duplicate, pretty much the same issue as far I can see.